# Does Qt allready have its own new and delete operators?

Tags: c++, qt, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm using a `QGraphicsScene` widget and showing upon it some points as `QGraphicsRectItem`.

This means calling lots of `new` + `addItem()` when showing up, and `removeItem()` + `delete` to get rid of unused points.

Of course, for performance issues, I've implemented my own `new` and `delete` operators, which basically recycle pre-allocated memory chunks.

Those operators works very well with anything, except for **Qt** classes (I mean **QObject** derived classes). The error raised is different every time but always occurs during an internal call after all my slot functions have been executed with no errors.

I also tried them with some instances of `QWidget` added to some layouts etc.

So the question is, does **Qt** allready have its own `new` and delete `operators`, which I am totally skipping defining my own ones?

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: Cool! But we need code. See also: [Must I replace global operators new and delete to change memory allocation strategy in third party code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377991/must-i-replace-global-operators-new-and-delete-to-change-memory-allocation-strat)

Comment: As far as I know (exploring the Qt's code) there is no operator replacement in Qt.

Comment: Instead of using custom new and delete, have you considered using `addItem` and `removeItem` of `QGraphicsScene` to add and remove and re-add items without destroying them? That sounds like it might be the most efficient solution for your performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial enough to inspect Qt's headers to ascertain whether such custom operators exist. They don't.

The `QGraphicsRectItem` does *not* derive from `QObject`, so that's not an issue anyway. You're not getting as much savings from that as you think you are, since Qt uses the PIMPL idiom extensively, and `QGraphicsItem` is allocating its PIMPL on the heap.

You'd also need to show the implementation of your operator - for all I know, you're not maintaining proper alignment. What compiler(s) are you targeting? What version of Qt?

To do what you intend, you must modify Qt. Declare and implement:

```
void* QGraphicsItem::operator new (size_t sz)
void* QGraphicsItem::operator new[] (std::size_t count)
void QGraphicsItem::operator delete (void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
void QGraphicsItem::operator delete[] (void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
void* QGraphicsItemPrivate::operator new (size_t sz)
void QGraphicsItemPrivate::operator delete (void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
```

Make sure that your allocator properly aligns the storage.

Comment: It is not too much trivial since if they are redefined as "global", new and delete operators have a special linkage rule that permits them to never appear in any header file. Anyway, I totally agree with you about PIMPL making almost useless this kind of approach.