# Qt and custom allocators

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QtCore, QtGUI, QtWidget with C++ and would need to track memory allocations to fix huge performance issues in my project. I have custom tracking mechanism, but would need to override malloc/new for the internal allocations that Qt does. Googled for a malloc hook or callback or something like that that Qt provides, but couldn't find. Can anyone tell me if there is a direct way to inform Qt to use custom allocators?

Comment: what platform are you on?  valgrind is the standard for unix based setups.

Comment: QT is QuickTime, Qt is the C++ library, please make sure to use the correct one when referring to the C++ library.

Comment: Can't you use something like Valgrind/Callgrind (linux) or another profiling tool to find such issues without having to create custom allocators?

Comment: Rather than implmenting your own allocator, you should think about using Qt Smart Pointers: https://wiki.qt.io/Smart_Pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to define own debug new and delete operators. There is a relative question for that: [Does Qt allready have its own new and delete operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931668/does-qt-allready-have-its-own-new-and-delete-operators) I can trust the answer from there and the task is about redefining C++ own operators then.

But mind that we want global scope operators covering all C++ allocations: [How to properly replace global new & delete operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186018/how-to-properly-replace-global-new-delete-operators)