# How to control memory allocation of a third party library?

Tags: c++, memory-management, numa

I am developing a real-time application on a server with two NUMA nodes. Below is a simplified version of the system diagram (the OS is Ubuntu14.04):

```
.-------------.          .-------------.
| Device 0    |          | Device 1    |
.-------------.          .-------------.
      ||                       ||
      ||                       ||
.-------------.          .-------------.
| PCIE slot 0 |          | PCIE slot 1 |
.-------------.          .-------------.
      ||                       ||
      ||                       ||
.-------------. QPI link .-------------.
| CPU 0       |<-------->| CPU 1       |
.-------------.          .-------------.
      ||                       ||
      ||                       ||
.-------------.          .-------------.
| Mem node 0  |          | Mem node 1  |
.-------------.          .-------------.
```

The two devices do exactly the same thing,  but each of them consumes all the power of one CPU so I have to create two threads to control them separately.  Also I have to use a third party library to control the two devices.
Although I can use `numa_alloc` to allocate memory on a local node in my own thread that doesn't change the way how the third party library allocates its own memory.

**First**: If I run the program with only one device with `numactl --membind` I get very good performance.

**Second**: If I run the program with two devices without `numactl --membind` I get relatively good performance for both of the devices but if I run it for a long time the performance is not so stable.

**Thrid**: If I run the program with two devices together with`numactl --membind`, say `numactl --membind=0`, then device 0 performs quite well but not device 1, and vice verse.

Base on the above observations, I suspect that memory locality is the performance bottleneck here.

**My question**: Can I put some sort of constraints in my thread so that everything inside that thread is allocated on a specific NUMA node, including those of a third party library?

Comment: Do you have source code of the library? If you do and it uses new, you can always override the new and delete operators. Otherwise, I don't think there is a way to control the allocations of a pre-built library.

Comment: @patatahooligan, yes it's open source. It's interesting that new/delete can be overloaded. But will that have some side effects/impacts of the program?

Comment: If their library already provides a new operator you might break something. Most new operators outside of debugging are used to align data so you should be safe to replace them as long as you enforce the same or strictrer alignment. If you do, make sure to replace their implementation. Having multiple definitions for a new operator causes undefined behavior!

Comment: Related: [How to control memory allocation strategy in third party library code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377991/how-to-control-memory-allocation-strategy-in-third-party-library-code)