# Capping allocated memory in multi-threaded C++ library

Tags: c++, multithreading, allocation

I've developed a library in C++ that allows multi-threaded usage.  I want to support an option for the caller to specify a cap on the memory allocated by a given thread.  (We can ignore the case of one thread allocating memory and others using it.)

Possibly making this more complicated is that my library uses various open source components (boost, ICU, etc), some of which are statically linked and others dynamically.

One option I've been looking into is overriding the allocation functions (new/delete/etc) to do the bookkeeping per thread ID.  Natural concerns come up around the bookkeeping:  performance, etc.
But an even bigger question/concern is whether this approach will work with the open source components without code changes to them?

I can't seem to find pre-existing solutions for this, though it seems to me like it's not very unusual.

Any suggestions on this approach, or another approach?

EDIT:  More background:  The library can allocate a significantly large range of memory per calling thread depending on the input provided (ie. KBs to GBs).
So the goal of this request is to (more graciously & deterministically) support running in RAM-constrained environments.  This is not for a hard-real-time environment with strict memory limits--it's to support a number of concurrent threads which each have a "safe" allocation cap to avoid engaging the page/swap file.

Basic example use case:  a system with 32GB RAM, 20GB free, the application using my library may configure itself to use a max of 10 threads and configure the library to use a max of 1GB per thread.

Upon hitting the cap the current thread's call into the library will cease further work and return a suitable error.  (The code is already fully RAII so unwinding cleanly is easy.)

BTW I found some interesting content on the web already, sadly none provide a lot of hope for a "simple & effective" solution.  But [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377991/how-to-control-memory-allocation-strategy-in-third-party-library-code) is especially insightful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Assuming you could hook new / delete / malloc / free, what would you like to happen when you decide a thread has reached its memory cap?

Comment: @hfhc2 I've added more background & answer to your question in the post.